# Place Azure AD B2C KMSI checkbox below the Sign In button

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using custom policies and the keep me signed in (KMSI) feature of Azure AD B2C and now I would like to place the KMSI checkbox below the "Sign In" button, instead of above it.

***Instead of this:***
[image]

***I would like to have something like this:***
[image]

I didn't find a way to configure the order of the elements.
Is there such a functionality? Otherwise I can inject/move the element with javascript.

KMSI feature is described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-kmsi-custom

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a combination of CSS and JavaScript to style the page as required.
Custom Policies:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom

Built in Policies:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-javascript-overview
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview